# Is it correct if I complete a sentence with "Before"?

Tags: sentence, sentence-ends

I'm asking for the correct format of this sentence:

> My friend: "Can we go for a walk?"
>
> Me: "Sorry, but I have a python course and I need to complete it *before*".

Is it correct to say this?

Comment: I'm sure that people would just ask "Before _what_?". What are you trying to achieve by using _before_ here?

Comment: I missed something , I will edit my question

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: "...I need to complete it _first_." would be more natural. If you want to use _before_, as @KillingTime suggests, , you have to say "before I go out" or "before I do anything else."

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting , please put your comment as an answer.

Comment: The problem is your use of “Sorry”.  Sorry means “No”. But the rest of your sentence means “Yes, but only after I finish my python course”

Comment: *Before* can be used on its own when it represents a **non-bounded** period up until that given point. In other words although there must be an end point to that period, it cannot be restricted by a beginning point. In your example *before* can’t be used because the start of the period represented by *before* is limited by the present. It is being used to mean ‘at some point between  now and then’. The start of that period is defined and thus *before* cannot be used on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct to end *some sentences* with "before", for example:

> I just typed the homework for my Python course with my toes.  I've never done that **before**!

The example you gave might be understood, but would be more correctly worded as:

> Sorry, but I have a python course and I need to complete it **beforehand**.

or

> Sorry, but I have a python course and I need to complete it **first**.

Comment: Why? ............,,,,

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The OP didn't ask why; they only asked whether.  I think other answers have it covered.

Answer (score 1):

Although 'before' *can* be used without a prepositional complement ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/before) uses the traditional classification *adverb* here while CGEL doubtless considers this an *intransitive preposition*), the other event in question needs to be specified, and will be a notional noun phrase:

> **before**:  During the period of time preceding a particular [overtly mentioned, or understood] event or time.
>
> - *My playing days had ended six years before* [eg *the time just mentioned*]

the implied 'completer' here ('I come for a walk', etc) is too complex to qualify. It is an independent clause, and 'uncompleted conjunctions' are not recognised.

Some more examples, one unacceptable in standard English:

- After the Great War, women had far more influence in politics than before.
- "Are you still playing cricket now you're married?" ... "No, I have far less time than I had before."
- "I've never driven a tractor before." (ie before now or the time mentioned)
- *"Can we go for a walk?" ... "Sorry, but I have a python course and I need to complete it before." [independent clause missing; ungrammatical.]
- "Can we go for a walk?" ... "Sorry, but I have a python course and I need to complete it before I can come with you."

Answer (score 1):

You can complete a sentence with *before*, but only if you’re using *before* adverbially, where it means, roughly, *prior to now*:

> *I’ve never seen that before.*
> *The economy will grow at the same rate as before.*

You can see more examples from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English — *before .*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100538939)

But your *before* is a conjunction, and you’ve left off **the other half** of what it’s “conjuncting”:

> *I have a Python course, and I need to complete it before **I can go for a walk**.*

You can find more examples of *before* as an adverb, preposition, and conjunction at [Collins — *before*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/before).

What you need is an adverb, like *first* or *beforehand*.

Answer (score 1):

**Before** can be used at the end of a sentence.

I have not seen him **before**. (present perfect tense)
Have you been to London **before**? (present perfect tense)
I had not seen a tiger before. (past perfect tense)

I have seen him **before**. (present perfect tense)
I saw him three years **ago**. (simple past tense)
**Before** is used in the perfect tense while **ago** is used with the simple past tense.